# Laravel eloquet check non existing many to many relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm having trouble to write query in laravel eloquent ORM.

I have a proyect table, where you can assign users, in a many to many relationship

In the view to asign users, I have a selector, but I want to show only the users not already assigned to the proyect and checking also that the user belongs to the company that created the proyect (user.company_id=proyect_id)

In a normal query should me something like this, having $company_id and $proyect_id from the controller.

> select * from users u left join proyect_user pu on u.id=pu.user_id and
> pu.proyect_id = $proyect_id where u.company_id=$company_i and
> proyect_id is null;

The query works, but I would like to use Eloquent. ¿Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you declared the relationship in the User model. But I would do something like this:

```
$users = User::whereHas('company', function ($query) use ($companyId) {
    $query->where('id', $companyId)
 })->whereDoesntHave('proyects', function ($query) use ($proyectId) {
    $query->where('id', $proyectId);
 })->get();
```